# Using diff / patch to create a new file inside a directory

Tags: shell-script, shell, diff, patch

I'm learning about diff/patch and I don't understand why the patch file created by the command sequence below doesn't create the file `create_me.txt` inside the `Org` directory when I try to apply it.

#### Creating a file

```bsh
$ ls -R
Org Upd

./Org:

./Upd:
create_me.txt
$ diff -ruN Org/ Upd/ > Org.patch
$ cat Org.patch 
diff -ruN Org/create_me.txt Upd/create_me.txt
--- Org/create_me.txt   1970-01-01 01:00:00.000000000 +0100
+++ Upd/create_me.txt   2019-06-30 21:12:36.000000000 +0200
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+content
$ patch -p0 < Org.patch 
The next patch would create the file Upd/create_me.txt,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
```

The `-N --new-file` flag treats absent files such as `create_me.txt` as empty files with a default timestamp inside the directory where it is missing. Deleting a file using the `-N` flag (see below) works perfectly but the reverse operation results in the error message seen in the command sequence above which I can't wrap my head around.

#### Deleting a file

```bsh
$ ls -R
Org Upd

./Org:
delete_me.txt identical.txt

./Upd:
identical.txt
$ diff -ruN Org/ Upd/ > Org.patch
$ cat Org.patch 
diff -ruN Org/delete_me.txt Upd/delete_me.txt
--- Org/delete_me.txt   2019-06-30 21:32:50.000000000 +0200
+++ Upd/delete_me.txt   1970-01-01 01:00:00.000000000 +0100
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-content
$ patch -p0 < Org.patch 
patching file Org/delete_me.txt
$ ls -R
Org       Org.patch Upd

./Org:
identical.txt

./Upd:
identical.txt
```

I have seen two duplicate questions to this one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528758/how-to-create-patch-for-a-new-file-and-patch-it-back-to-the-original-directory,
https://askubuntu.com/questions/975879/patch-command-cant-create-the-new-file) but none of the answers satisfy me. These answers solve the problem by changing the working directory to the original directory in which the file is going to be created and applying the patch from there. This approach works but it isn't scalable to what I'm hoping to use diff/patch for and I would therefore love a more broad solution which can be used from any directory and uses the `-p0` patch flag.

#### Current answer's way to create a file

```bsh
$ ls -R
Org Upd

./Org:
identical.txt

./Upd:
create_me.txt identical.txt
$ diff -ruN Org/ Upd/ > Org.patch
$ cat Org.patch 
diff -ruN Org/create_me.txt Upd/create_me.txt
--- Org/create_me.txt   1970-01-01 01:00:00.000000000 +0100
+++ Upd/create_me.txt   2019-06-30 21:53:09.000000000 +0200
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+content
$ cd Org
$ patch -p1 < ../Org.patch
patching file create_me.txt
$ ls -R ..
Org       Org.patch Upd

../Org:
create_me.txt identical.txt

../Upd:
create_me.txt identical.txt
```

An explanation to why the current answer works and my version doesn't would also be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first patch, and the way you’re applying it, is asking `patch` to create a file named `Upd/create_me.txt`, not `Org/create_me.txt`: the full path is significant. When `patch` sees an entry dated at the epoch (170-01-01 00:00:00 UTC), it knows that that represents a non-existent file; if it’s the “start” entry, it knows it’s supposed to create a file, and if it’s the “end” entry, it knows it’s supposed to delete a file. The name of the file to be created or deleted is taken from the *other* entry.

Your second patch works in the same way: it tells `patch` to delete `Org/delete_me.txt`.

Your third approach works because you’re telling `patch` to ignore the first part of the path, *i.e.* `Org` or `Upd`. Thus it creates a file named `create_me.txt` in the current directory, `Org`.

To get your first example to work, you can replace `Upd/create_me.txt` with `Org/create_me.txt` in the patch.

Comment: I guess it's OK to ask an opinion in Comments, so here goes: This `diff & patch` procedure seems well-suited to upgrading a bunch of configuration files (think `/etc`) after upgrading an OS (e.g. from `buster` to `bullseye`) when an *in-place* upgrade isn't possible. IOW, `diff -ruN etc-buster/ etc-bseye/ > etc-bseye.patch`. Do you know of any projects/scripts that do this?

Comment: I don’t see a question about an opinion there. I’ll answer anyway, because my answer isn’t very useful — I don’t know of anything that does this.

Comment: You're correct; I guess the implied question was, "Do you think that approach might be useful?"

Comment: I’ve never run into a situation where it would be all that useful, but that doesn’t mean it wouldn’t be useful for you. On systems where changes to `/etc` are important, I track them using `etckeeper`, but I’ve never needed to copy a set of changes from such a system to another, wholesale. When I was a sysadmin at a meaningful scale I used Ansible to set everything up anyway, systems weren’t managed individually.